# Difference between two separate tables and one table with column

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have `users` and `doctors`. It is an app that both regular people and doctors can use. I'm not sure which way to setup my database.

1. Two tables - `users` and `doctors` tables
2. One table, extra column - `users` table with column `user_type`

Which one is the best way to do it? What are the pros and cons of both?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping separate tables for me is good especially if you make user table to be as basic as possible (with username and password). This way you know that even if requirements changes in the future and you need to add another user type with other additional fields, then you don't have to worry about other sections of your code. I am just thinking about the future changes or additions. Doctors is abstract. Again this might be the problem in the future when you have to categorize them (e.g by their specialty).

Just my two cents worth.

Answer (score 0):

2 tables is your best approach. Although not the 2 tables you have suggested.

If you analyze your situation a little more basically, you have users and they belong to 1 of 2 groups (general public and doctors).

This is a standard user group situation, so using 1 table to store user specific data with a reference to a user_group table (ie user belongs to  group) is a good solution.

This also allows you to add groups later on - renal patient, renal doctor, cardiac patient, cardiac doctor ...

Using a setup with users and user_groups is usually a good way to go.